# how to get first column value of an html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which is dynamically created now I want to get its first column inner text or value using a JavaScript function.

for example

```
name    roll-no    class 
-----   -------    -----
alpha      1        11A
beta       2        11B
gama       3        11C
```

How can I get first column values in array like this `name = [alpha,beta,gama]`

My tbody name is :

`tbody = document.getElementById('perf');`

Comment: Share the HTML and what is `perf`?

Comment: perf is tbody id

Comment: HTML is balnk as its dynamically created.

Comment: Then show example HTML.  Is jQuery an option?

Comment: No Only Javascript and what is with showing the html it will confuse your more. anyways I am adding it to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var terf = document.getElementById('terf');
var firstChilds = terf.querySelectorAll("td:first-child");
var allName = [];
for(i=0; i<firstChilds.length; ++i){
  allName.push(firstChilds[i].innerHTML);
}

console.log(allName);
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>roll-no</td>
        <td>class</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="terf">
    <tr>
        <td>alpha</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>11A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>beta</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>12B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>gamma</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>13C</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following...

`document.querySelectorAll("#perf td:first-child")` will return a NodeList of all the first `<td>` elements in the `id="perf"` table body.

`Array.from` will turn the NodeList into an array

`.map(x => x.innerHTML)` will return an array of just the contents of each `<td>`

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#perf td:first-child")).map(x => x.innerHTML));
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>name</th>
   <th>roll-no</th>
   <th>class</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="perf">
  <tr>
   <td>alpha</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>11A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>beta</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>11B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>gama</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>11C</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice and concise solution(+1) . `.textContent` is probably a better choice than `.innerHTML` as OP requested to get the table's  _first column inner text or value_ .

Answer (score -1):

Add a class name to the column cells. Select the class!

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down. Simplicity is key!